# how to perform multi-select with perform(withKeyModifier:block:) function in XCUITest

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I want to multiple-select some element on the webview, therefore I would need to use perform(withKeyModifer:block:) function of XCUIElement, can any one give an example on how to use this function? I'm new to swift so please elaborate the code, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the method to perform some code while a modifier key is down. You specify the modifier key and pass in a block of code to execute while the key modifier is down. You can use trailing closure syntax for this like so:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()

// elements you want to select
let element1 = app.cells.element(boundBy: 0)
let element2 = app.cells.element(boundBy: 1)
let elementsToSelect = [element1, element2]

XCUIElement.perform(withKeyModifiers: XCUIElement.KeyModifierFlags.command) {
    // code in this block executes while the command key is down
    // select each element
    elementsToSelect.forEach({ $0.tap() })
}
```

If you are testing a desktop app, you should use `click()` instead of `tap()`.

Use whichever modifier key you need from the list here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement.keymodifierflags

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm just confused by the "+" "-" signal before the function.

Comment: @Wayne + means it is a class method, - means it is an instance method. As it is a class method, I'll update my example to call the perform method on the type - sorry I didn't notice that!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Can you have a quick look at this question if you got time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233901/how-to-simulate-scroll-down-up-with-mouse-in-xcuitest-runing-on-macos